# .jpeg images based on certain GIS area

Tags: file-geodatabase

How to add JPEG images as vector data?

My requirement is if I should able to add few people data as a vector data on different layers such as Name. Ph.No, Village name, zip along with his photo. I use Erdas Imagine , ArcGis, Global Mapper and Gogle Earth. My requirement is add this information on Google Earth.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Images are raster data. They can be vectorized in some cases, but it's unclear if that's what you want to do. Are you trying to extract information from a jpg to attributes? Are you trying to add an image as an attribute or an attachment to a point or something?

Comment: Would you be able to **edit** your question to include the GIS software that you are using, please?  Also, as a new user be sure to take the [Tour], if you have not already.

Comment: Hi Chris,My requirement is, I need to add few people image (Jpeg) data as vector along with other field such as name ,ph no and all with reference to certain geo area or a geo point .If i browse through or click on certain area on Google Earth, these information should poop up. Right now i could able add image to a place mark on Google earth. Its not working well . need some clarification or best method to achieve my requirement.

Comment: Does this help: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/38922/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to work with the JPEG image, if your data is formatted correctly, you could have each person as a single entry in the data table, with the lat/long coordinates and all of the attributes of that person (Name, phone, village, filename of photo, etc.) as columns in your table. This could be imported as a spreadsheet and converted to X-Y data, so it create vector data (point shapefile) from the get-go instead of having to work with raster images.

To attach your geotagged photos to your point shapefile that contains all the demographic information, use [Geotagged Photos to Points](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000165000000), under the Data Management Toolbox, using your shapefile as the output layer.

Once you have a shapefile with linked photos, you can use Conversion Tools' [To KML Toolset](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/An_overview_of_the_To_KML_toolset/00120000002n000000/) to convert the shapefile into .kml, which Google Earth can use. I haven't done this myself, so I'm unsure of how the conversion to kml keeps the photos linked or requires linking them once in Google Earth.